# Sort an array of objects by deeply nested property selected from an adjacent value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I'm making a call to a REST API and it returns an array of objects. Some of them contain further arrays with objects inside, as in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [OPPORTUNITY_ID] => 7443729
            [CUSTOMFIELDS] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [CUSTOM_FIELD_ID] => OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7
                            [FIELD_VALUE] => Zorem
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [CUSTOM_FIELD_ID] => OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_8
                            [FIELD_VALUE] => Zappem
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [OPPORTUNITY_ID] => 7401996
            [CUSTOMFIELDS] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [CUSTOM_FIELD_ID] => OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7
                            [FIELD_VALUE] => Aorem
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [CUSTOM_FIELD_ID] => OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_8
                            [FIELD_VALUE] => Arappem
                        )
                )
        )

    // [etc.]

)
```

What I would like to do is sort the first-level objects in the array based on either `OPPORTUNITY_ID` or on `CUSTOM_FIELD_ID` / `FIELD_VALUE`.

As a scenario, a user would click on the link: "Sort by OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7" and the array element `[1]` would become `[0]` because "Aorem" has a higher alphabetical value than "Zorem".

I've managed to sort the first level objects using `usort`:

```
function sort_results( $a, $b ) {
    if ($a->OPPORTUNITY_ID == $b->OPPORTUNITY_ID) return 0;
    else if ($a->OPPORTUNITY_ID > $b->OPPORTUNITY_ID) return -1;
    else return 1;
}
usort( $json_opportunities, "sort_results" );
```

But I don't know how to get off first base on sorting by level 2 values like `OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7`. Any suggestions? Do I need to push everything into an array and sort that way, or is there a way to sort without rewriting the array first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need a more advanced callback for [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). For example, sorting the array using `OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7` would compare these values:

- `$restArray[0]->CUSTOMFIELDS[0]->FIELD_VALUE`
- `$restArray[1]->CUSTOMFIELDS[0]->FIELD_VALUE`

Because `OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7` is a value in the same array as the value we use to sort rather than being its index, we need to first find the numeric index to which it belongs. This is done by looping through `CUSTOMFIELDS` until we find `OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7`.

```
// callback for usort() using "OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7"
function sort_OF7($a, $b) {

    // get the index where "OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7" is stored
    foreach($a->CUSTOMFIELDS as $index => $arr) {
        if($arr->CUSTOM_FIELD_ID == 'OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7') {
            $ai = $index;
            break;
        }
    }

    // again
    foreach($b->CUSTOMFIELDS as $index => $arr) {
        if($arr->CUSTOM_FIELD_ID == 'OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7') {
            $bi = $index;
            break;
        }
    }

    // compare values
    return strcmp(
        $a->CUSTOMFIELDS[$ai]->FIELD_VALUE,
        $b->CUSTOMFIELDS[$bi]->FIELD_VALUE
    );
}
```

This assumes `OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7` is always available in the objects.

We can quickly test it:

```
// test
$main = JSON_decode('[{"OPPORTUNITY_ID":7443729,"CUSTOMFIELDS":[{"CUSTOM_FIELD_ID":"OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7","FIELD_VALUE":"Zorem"},{"CUSTOM_FIELD_ID":"OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_8","FIELD_VALUE":"Zappem"}]},{"OPPORTUNITY_ID":7401996,"CUSTOMFIELDS":[{"CUSTOM_FIELD_ID":"OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_7","FIELD_VALUE":"Aorem"},{"CUSTOM_FIELD_ID":"OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_8","FIELD_VALUE":"Arappem"}]}]');
print_r($main);
usort($main, 'sort_OF7');
print_r($main);
```